# word file not generating in firefox

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am using this code to generate a word file and download it from browser. this is working in chrome but not working in firefox
        a file is download but without extension.

```
    $this->loadModel ( 'Template' );
    $template = $this->Template->findById ( $template_id );
    $doc_body = $template['Template']['content'] ;      
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Expires: 0");//no-cache
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");//no-cache
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=".$template['Template']['title'].'-'.time().".doc");
    echo "<html>";
    echo "$doc_body";
    echo "</html>";  
    die;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to put this a part of code.

```
$filename = $template['Template']['title'].'-'.time().".doc";
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename\"");
```